# How to Enable Blob Driver in the Worker Nodes of an AKS Cluster?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-aks

I was trying to use Azure Blob Storage for my AKS cluster. First I enabled the Blob CSI Driver in the cluster by running the following command in the Azure cloud shell:

`az aks update --enable-blob-driver -n mycluster -g mygp`

Then I checked it by running:

`kubectl get sc`

And here was the result:

```
NAME                     PROVISIONER          RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
azureblob-fuse-premium   blob.csi.azure.com   Delete          Immediate              true                   39m
azureblob-nfs-premium    blob.csi.azure.com   Delete          Immediate              true                   39m
```

Then I created a Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) applying this .yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azure-blob-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azureblob-nfs-premium
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

The PVC was successfully created, as the command `kubectl get pvc` showed:

```
NAME                 STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS            AGE
azure-blob-storage   Bound    pvc-7156b751-644c-4d21-829e-037ddf7528c4   1Gi        RWX            azureblob-nfs-premium   24m
```

Then I mounted the PVC to my pod, using this .yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo2-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongo2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo2
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: azure-blob-storage
      containers:
      - name: mongo2db
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo2-secret
              key: mongo-user
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo2-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo2-config
              key: mongo-dbase
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/data/db"
            name: volume
            readOnly: false
```

But when I applied the above .yaml, the pod was stuck at "Creating" status. When I ran the command `kubectl describe pod/<pod_name>`, the following message showed:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    95s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mongo2-deployment-7b9ddbf54b-6p2wr to aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000j
  Warning  FailedMount  32s (x8 over 95s)  kubelet            MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-527cc87f-b369-41c5-a571-ed2c57fd4c3f" : kubernetes.io/csi: attacher.MountDevice failed to create newCsiDriverClient: driver name blob.csi.azure.com not found in the list of registered CSI drivers
```

Then I tried to look at whether the nodes had the Blob Driver, and I found this by running `kubectl describe csinodes aks-agentpool-13168364-vmss00000c`:

```
Spec:
  Drivers:
    disk.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-agentpool-13168364-vmss00000c
      Allocatables:
        Count:        4
      Topology Keys:  [topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone topology.kubernetes.io/zone]
    file.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-agentpool-13168364-vmss00000c
    blob.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-agentpool-13168364-vmss00000c
```

But when I ran `kubectl describe csinodes aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000j`, I found blob.csi.azure.com was not in the user node pool:

```
Spec:
  Drivers:
    disk.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000j
      Allocatables:
        Count:        4
      Topology Keys:  [topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone topology.kubernetes.io/zone]
    file.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000j
```

I believe that was the reason why my pod failed to start. But how can I register the blob.csi.azure.com in the user node pool?

p.s. My AKS cluster is a Linux cluster, both for the agent node pool and the user node pool.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Blob Driver did not appear in the user node pool yet (but at least it was not there for about half an hour after I enabled the driver, this can be proved as the pvc existed for 24 minutes as the question showed). I stopped the cluster and restarted it the next day and the Blob Driver then appeared, as shown by the output of the `kubectl describe csinodes aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000j` command:

```
Spec:
  Drivers:
    disk.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000k
      Allocatables:
        Count:        4
      Topology Keys:  [topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone topology.kubernetes.io/zone]
    file.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000k
    blob.csi.azure.com:
      Node ID:  aks-userpool-13168364-vmss00000k
Events:         <none>
```

The MongoDB Pod then worked upon restart.